# What is the best way to type such a nested object?

Tags: typescript

what is the best way to type such a nested object?
I know that each object can simply be registered separately, but this option is not the best

```
const dateButtons = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'All',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD MMM YYYY', time: true },
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    title: '11 10 2022',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD MM YYYY' },
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    title: '20:11 11.10.2022',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD.MM.YYYY', time: true },
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    title: '11-10-2022',
    sortBy: { date: 'DD-MM-YYYY' },
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    title: '11 oct Thu',
    sortBy: { date: 'Do MMM dddd' },
  },
};
```

if it was an array, then I would just write

```
type myButtons = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  sortBy: { date: string; time?: boolean };
}[];
```

Comment: Why not having an array instead of an object?

Comment: because in the reducer it is easier to get an item and change something for it

Comment: I see, so it is not ordered it is just a kv-store. Index type is your  friend `type ButtonStorage = { [key: Button["id"]]: Button }`

Comment: Thanks! maybe you know why my editor gives such an error "Parsing error unexpected token, expected "]"". but in the ts sandbox everything works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
interface ButtonData {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  sortBy: { date: string; time?: boolean };
}

type DateButtons = { [key in number]: ButtonData }

const dateButtons: DateButtons = {
   // ..
}
```

to specify that each key in your object is a number and each value is a `ButtonData`.